# Checkbox change event - jquery 1.10.12

Tags: php, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm having trouble with a checkbox search filter.

I am using jquery 1.10.2 and have had mixed results while testing other solutions online but I cannot get this working.

Scenario:

I have category tables as follows:
level 1 - main cat
level 2 - sub cat
level 3 - sub cat
The categories options are displayed with checkboxes using a css dropdown menu.

Each category checkbox has two jquery functions as follows:

Function 1 -: slideUp/Down results displayed on page in ul/li.

Function 2 -: level 1 and 2 checkboxes must check/uncheck level 2 and 3 checkboxes respectively

**slideUp/Down function**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.results > li').hide();

        $('div.tags').find('input:checkbox').on('change', function () {
            $('.results > li').slideUp(400);
            $('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function () {
                $('.results > li.' + $(this).attr('rel')).slideDown(400);
            });
        });
    });  
</script>
```

As there are many categories I have opted to use php to write the 
**check/uncheck functions:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
$catdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories order by catname;");
    while ($catdatarow = mysql_fetch_array($catdata)) {
        echo("$(document).ready(function(){");
            echo("$(\"#cat" . $catdatarow['catid'] . "\").on('change', function(){");
                echo("$(\"." . $catdatarow['catid'] . "\").prop(\"checked\",$(\"#cat" . $catdatarow['catid'] . "\").prop(\"checked\"))");
            echo("})");
        echo("});");
    }
?>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
$subcatdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subcategories order by subcatname;");
    while ($subcatdatarow = mysql_fetch_array($subcatdata)) {
        echo("$(document).ready(function(){");
            echo("$(\"#subcat" . $subcatdatarow['subcatid'] . "\").on('change', function(){");
                echo("$(\"." . $subcatdatarow['subcatid'] . "\").prop(\"checked\",$(\"#subcat" . $subcatdatarow['subcatid'] . "\").prop(\"checked\"))");
            echo("})");
        echo("});");
    }
?>
</script>
```

**Problem:**
Whilst all the basic functions work as they should my problem is as follows:

If I click on a level 2 cat checkbox all the level 3 cat checkboxes are checked and if I click on a level 1 cat checkbox all the level 2 cat checkboxes are checked but according to my understanding when clicking a level 1 it should check level 2 AND then level 3 checkboxes for the same selection based on the 'change' event but this does not happen.

This problem also holds true for the slideUp/Down function as the li items are associated with the level 3 cat checkboxes. Manually clicking on a level 3 checkbox will cause an li item to slideUp/Down and one would assume that, given the change events, when clicking on a level 2 cat checkbox that checks all the level 3 cat checkboxes the li slideUp/Down would occur as the level 3 cat checkboxes have now changed but this too doesn't happen.

**Here is an example of the li results for the slideUp/Down:**

```
<ul class="results">
    <li class="1002">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding:15px;"><img src="images/image.jpg" alt="" width="60" height="80" border="0" /></td>
            <td style="padding:15px;"><h4>Result A</h4>Description</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now I know I must have something wrong or be missing something, could you please point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

**HTML for the categories:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" rel="1020" id="cat1020" />Level 1 Cat 1
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" rel="2465" id="subcat2465" class="1020" />Level 2 Cat 1
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" rel="2452" id="subcat2452" class="1020" />Level 2 Cat 2
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" rel="2464" id="subcat2464" class="1020" />Level 2 Cat 3
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" rel="2463" id="subcat2463" class="1020" />Level 2 Cat 4
                </li>
            </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" rel="1015" id="cat1015" />Level 1 Cat 2
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" rel="2346" id="subcat2346" class="1015" />Level 2 Cat 5
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" rel="2341" id="subcat2341" class="1015" />Level 2 Cat 6
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" rel="5006" class="2341" />Level 3 Cat 1
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" rel="5005" class="2341" />Level 3 Cat 2
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" rel="5004" class="2341" />Level 3 Cat 3
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" rel="2340" id="subcat2340" class="1015" />Level 2 Cat 7
                </li>
            </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why are you writing PHP within script tag??Remove the script tags from around it.

Comment: can you share the generated html with multiple levels

Comment: Though it's not necessarily an error, your while loops are creating multiple $(document).ready() functions. The same effect could be achieved by doing `<script> $(document).ready() {<?php while($catdatarow = mysql_fetch_array($catdata)){ ..} while($subcatdatarow = mysql_fetch_array($subcatdata)){.. } ?> }`. That's probably not the cause of the error but it's poor coding practice and adds a lot of complexity to the generated html/javascript that doesn't need to be there.

Comment: @Zword: Note that the PHP dynamically writes the script for each unique category id.

Comment: @ArunPJohny: the HTML is attached:

Comment: @elitechief21: Thank you, I have updated accordingly.

Comment: @vigilantis does the `rel` value of the checkbox holds the id of the element to be slide up/down

Comment: Can you post (or have you posted) the relevant HTML for the elements you want to slide up/down? The checking is [(relatively) easy](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yLHQ3/), but I don't know what I'm working with in order to slide things (or how the relationships are identified).

Comment: @vigilantis checkout http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Nzbq4/3/

Comment: @ArunPJohny: jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Nzbq4/3 that did it, thanks man you're a legend.
Please post as an answer for me to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.results > li').hide();
    $('ul input[type="checkbox"][rel]').change(function () {
        $(this).next('ul').find('> li > input')[this.checked ? 'not' : 'filter'](':checked').prop('checked', this.checked).trigger('change');
        var $target = $('.results li.' + $(this).attr('rel'));
        if (this.checked) {
            $target.stop(true, true).slideDown();
        } else {
            $target.stop(true, true).slideUp();
        }
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Nzbq4/)

Comment: Thanks again, this has not only helped me but taught me a lot. My beginner level is now more apparent than ever. :)

Comment: If at all possible I'd appreciate a better understanding of the code.

Comment: Arun, How can the "if (this.checked) {}" be changed to check for multiple classes, (categories), as the li that is to  slideUp/Down can belong to multiple categories, (<li class="1004 1008">), and if both are checked and one is unchecked the slideUp is triggered which should not be as the other is still checked?

Comment: @vigilantis can you clarify it again if there are two classes then you want to display it only if both the checkboxes are checked

Comment: If an li has to more than one class it should display when any one of the checkboxes are checked. At the moment if li has classes 1001 and 1002 and both are checked it displays if I uncheck 1002 it should still display as 1001 is still checked but it then hides.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44722/discussion-between-vigilantis-and-arun-p-johny)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is filter your results based on the upper level categories.  If this is the case I believe this line:

```
echo("$(\"." . $catdatarow['catid'] . "\").prop(\"checked\",$(\"#cat" . $catdatarow['catid'] . "\").prop(\"checked\"))");
```

and this line

```
echo("$(\"." . $subcatdatarow['subcatid'] . "\").prop(\"checked\",$(\"#subcat" . $subcatdatarow['subcatid'] . "\").prop(\"checked\"))");
```

need to be changed to

```
   echo("$(\"." . $catdatarow['catid'] . "\").each(function(){($this).prop(\"checked\",$(\"#cat" . $catdatarow['catid'] . "\"))}");
```

and

```
 echo("$(\"." . $subcatdatarow['subcatid'] . "\").each($(this).prop(\"checked\",$(\"#subcat" . $subcatdatarow['subcatid'] . "\"))}");
```

so that you are unchecking all checkboxes that are associated(via html classes) with a given parent category checkbox.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this worked too but I have decide to go with Arun's solution as it also cleaned up the script that was not up to standard as you first pointed out.